# Eloquent datatables not applying where(), orderBy(), etc

Tags: php, datatable, eloquent

I've written a class which takes an Eloquent Model and manipulates it in order to output JSON for a [datatable](https://datatables.net/). The datatable uses server side processing via a POST request.

Here is the class:

```
namespace App\Helpers;

class Datatable {
    public static $request;
    public static $model;
    public static $records_total;
    public static $records_filtered;

    static function make ($request, $model) {
        self::$request = $request;
        self::$model = $model;
        self::setRecordsTotal();
        self::filter();
        self::setRecordsFiltered();
        self::orderLimit();
        self::renderJson();
    }

    // set total record count
    static function setRecordsTotal () {
        self::$records_total = self::$model->count();
    }

    // filter by search query
    static function filter () {
        if (!empty(self::$request['search']['value'])) {
            foreach (self::$request['columns'] as $column) {
                if ($column['searchable'] == 'true') {
                    self::$model->where($column['data'], 'LIKE', '%'.self::$request['search']['value'].'%');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // set filtered record count
    static function setRecordsFiltered () {
        self::$records_filtered = self::$model->count();
    }

    // apply order by & limit
    static function orderLimit () {
        self::$model->orderBy(self::$request['columns'][self::$request['order'][0]['column']], self::$request['order'][0]['dir']);
        self::$model->skip(self::$request['start'])->take(self::$request['length']);
    }

    // render json output
    static function renderJson () {
        $array = [];
        $array['draw'] = self::$request['draw'];
        $array['recordsTotal'] = self::$records_total;
        $array['recordsFiltered'] = self::$records_filtered;
        $array['data'] = [];
        $results = self::$model->get();

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $array['data'][] = $result->toArray();
        }

        echo json_encode($array);
    }
}
```

Here is how I call the class:

```
Datatable::make($_POST, new User());
```

So `User` is an Eloquent model in this instance.

Now, the initial rendering of the datatable works great. However, when I try and search or order it, it seems like my code within the `filter()` and `orderLimit()` methods is not being applied, because it just keeps spitting out the exact same results in the exact same order.

Why are my `where()`, `orderBy()`, etc. not being applied to the Model properly?

Comment: I guess it's just cause of static binding. Not sure but you can try to rewrite methods to use $model not statically

Comment: What are you parsing as $model argument?

Comment: And this is why professional developers say, that Laravel is a procedural framework.

Comment: I only use a few packages from laravel, not the entire framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I just had to use `::query()` on the model in my `make()` method e.g:

`self::$model = $model::query()`.